# Python: Remove Exif info from images

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, exif, exiftool

In order to reduce the size of images to be used in a website, I reduced the quality to 80-85%. This decreases the image size quite a bit, up to an extent.

To reduce the size further without compromising the quality, my friend pointed out that raw images from cameras have a lot of metadata called Exif info. Since there is no need to retain this Exif info for images in a website, we can remove it. This will further reduce the size by 3-10 kB.

But I'm not able to find an appropriate library to do this in my Python code. I have browsed through related questions and tried out some of the methods:

Original image: http://mdb.ibcdn.com/8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i.jpg

1. [Mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html)

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/mogrify -strip filename
   ```

   Result: http://s23.postimg.org/aeaw5x7ez/8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i_mogrify.jpg
    This method reduces the size from 105 kB to 99.6 kB, but also changed the color quality.
2. [Exif-tool](https://exiftool.org/)

   ```
   exiftool -all= filename
   ```

   Result: http://s22.postimg.org/aiq99o775/8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i_exiftool.jpg
   This method reduces the size from 105 kB to 72.7 kB, but also changed the color quality.
3. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765396/exif-manipulation-library-for-python/765403#765403) explains in detail how to manipulate the Exif info, but how do I use it to remove the info?

Can anyone please help me remove all the extra metadata without changing the colours, dimensions, and other properties of an image?

Comment: You are wrong about ExifTool modifying 'color quality' (changing actual pixels? color? compression?). Compare original and result with IM's **compare**: `compare -metric AE 8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i.jpg 8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i_exiftool.jpg null:` and you'll get zero difference (or use **JPEGsnoop**, etc.). You may be confused because original has icc-profile embedded and result hasn't, and you compare them in color-managed application. But you can strip all but icc-profile: `exiftool -all= --icc_profile:all 8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i.jpg` and get 74.1 kb with icc-profile untouched

Comment: Regarding method 3 (Exif-py), it looks like that tool is for extracting Exif information from images so that you have access to it in your program, not for removing it from the image files.  I don't think it is designed to modify image files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try loading the image with the [Python Image Lirbary (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and then save it again to a different file. That should remove the meta data.

Comment: will this cost a lot of IO?

Comment: Will not work if the metadata is too large though, https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2445.

Comment: this method works in my unit tests with Pillow 6.x. It also uses substantially less memory than the accepted answer.

Comment: this answer would be improved with a code sample as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51213844/1449799

Comment: yes, That is not correct. PLEASE DON'T DO IT! –

Answer (score 50):

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image_file.jpeg')
    
# next 3 lines strip exif
data = list(image.getdata())
image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
image_without_exif.putdata(data)
    
image_without_exif.save('image_file_without_exif.jpeg')

# as a good practice, close the file handler after saving the image.
image_without_exif.close()
```

Comment: In case Image.open(...) is not working for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230991/image-open-cannot-identify-image-file-python

Comment: I just tried out this method. With the image given in the question, the file size was reduced from 106 KB to 63 KB.

Comment: This breaks some images, e.g. https://www.bk.com/sites/default/files/Hero_0001_Chocolate_Milk.png

Comment: If this breaks certain images, such as the PNG identified above by @Gallaecio (which is no longer available) it is probably because the image has a palette which is not propagated forward to the new image, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621

Comment: This function works but is not suitable for Production code. During high load times, I've seen this function take north of 15s, which is a HUGE bottleneck. If we can optimize it in some way, that would be great!

Answer (score 12):

For me, [`gexiv2`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import GExiv2

exif = GExiv2.Metadata('8snmhp4sjd75vdr27gbadolc003i.jpg')
exif.clear_exif()
exif.clear_xmp()
exif.save_file()
```

See also [Exif manipulation library for python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966425/2604213), which you linked, but didn't read all answers ;)

Answer (score 6):

You don't even need to do the extra steps @user2141737 suggested. Just opening it up with PIL and saving it again seems to do the trick just fine:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('path/to/image')
image.save('new/path/' + file_name)
```

Comment: That seems false? I still see all kinds of metadata when doing it via pil like you say.

Comment: yes, That is not correct. PLEASE DON'T DO IT!

Answer (score 2):

As for `pillow==9.2.0`

This seems to print exif data, a mutable mapping

```
print(im.info)
```

This seems to clear exif data for PNG

```
def clear_exif():
with Image.open('./my_image.png', mode='r', formats=['PNG']) as im:
    fields_to_keep = ('transparency', )
    exif_fields = list(im.info.keys())
    for k in exif_fields:
        if k not in fields_to_keep:
            del im.info[k]

    im.save('./my_image.png', format='PNG')
```