# Removing EXIF information from photos getting uploaded in a Django app

Tags: python, django, exif

I'm having issues with photos getting rotated upon upload in my Django app. I have pinpointed the issue to EXIF data that tells the browser to rotate the images.

For example:

```
Make                            : Apple
Camera Model Name               : iPhone 4
Orientation                     : Rotate 90 CW
```

What is the recommended way of removing EXIF data from Images in a python Django app? Among other things, I also don't want EXIF data for privacy reasons.

Comment: You should look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786301/python-remove-exif-info-from-images), if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it looks like the photos need to be uploaded first before removing the EXIF information? This is ok, but it would be better if there was an existing Django solution to remove the exif upon user upload of the image -- this would be taken care of in the views.py file in the request.POST