# How can I remove EXIF data from a dataset?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, deep-learning, exif

I am trying to remove EXIF data from images in a dataset (which I will use in transfer learning). However, it does not seem to be working. Below is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import piexif
import imghdr
from tqdm import tqdm
import warnings

Folder = 'drive/My Drive/PetImages'
labels =['Dog', 'Cat']
for label in labels:
  imageFolder = os.path.join(Folder, label)  
  listImages = os.listdir(imageFolder)
  for img in tqdm(listImages):
      imgPath = os.path.join(imageFolder,img)

      try:
        img = Image.open(imgPath)
        data = list(img.getdata())
        image_without_exif = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
        image_without_exif.putdata(data)
        image_without_exif.save(img)
        print("done")
      except:
        print("except")
```

I tried saving the image using PIL (as per a previously asked question: [Python: Remove Exif info from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786301/python-remove-exif-info-from-images)) but the output is purely composed of "except"s.

I tried again using the piexif module, as below:

```
# Same imports as above
Folder = 'drive/My Drive/PetImages'
labels =['Dog', 'Cat']
for label in labels:
  imageFolder = os.path.join(Folder, label)  
  listImages = os.listdir(imageFolder)
  for img in tqdm(listImages):
      imgPath = os.path.join(imageFolder,img)

      try:
          ImageType = img.format
          # warnings.filterwarnings("error")
          if ImageType in ["JPEG", "TIF", "WAV"]:
            exif_data = img._getexif()
            print(exif_data)
            piexif.remove(img)
            print("done")
      except:
        print("except")
```

In the code above, I check for the image type first to make sure the method _getexif() actually exists, then I just remove the data after saving it in exif_data variable. The output consisted of "except"s and the occasional exif data (in the form of a dictionary) or "None" if it doesn't exist but never the word "done". Why doesn't it reach that part?

Comment: It's a one-liner with `exiftool`...

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I googled ```exiftool``` but I am unsure how to use it within my program.

Comment: Have a look here... https://askubuntu.com/a/824059

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it is simple to use. If I may ask, can I use ```pip install exiftool``` in google colab? It doesn't work, but is there a similar way like an import?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Colab. `exiftool` is a Perl script, if that helps explain anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I solved my issue thanks to you.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this through Google, there is a simple solution using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('some-image.jpg')
# this clears all exif data
im.getexif().clear()
im.save('some-image-without-exif.jpg')
```

I thought that `getexif()` only allows read access as the name might imply, but it turns out that this is not the case.

Edit: In my case, it even worked to just load and save the file, without `im.getexif().clear()`. I don't know how reliable that is, though.
That command definitely removes exif-data from the image-object, though. This can be simply tested in a Python shell:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open('some-image.jpg')
>>> print(im.getexif())
{296: 2, 282: 72.0, 283: 72.0 ..... }
>>> im.getexif().clear()
>>> print(im.getexif())
{}
```